# Add an external folder to a C++ (NDK) project in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++

Part of my source code is in a parent directory to the Android NDK project, basically:

```
repo\
    sample-1\
        Android\
            <Standard Android project with Java & C++>
        Windows\
        ...
        Common\
```

I would like, from the `Android` project, to reference source and include files in this `Common` directory. I can't seem to figure how to do that. I mean, I can reference them from CMakeLists.txt, and it will compile, but they don't appear in Android Studio. The only files that it wants to show me are what is under `app\src\main\cpp` from the Android project.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found out that Android Studio would automatically create modules (which look like modules but are not, strictly speaking; they get defined in `.idea/workspace.xml` but it doesn't seem really user-editable), if you add source files from different folders. So basically it's about the source files you define in `CMakeLists.txt`. It doesn't work if you #include a cpp file, nor for include directories. Include directories still somehow ended up showing, but it seems random.

```
add_library(minimalandroid SHARED
        android_util/AndroidOut.cpp
        android_standalone_main.cpp
        ${TemplateRootDir}/c++/instance.cpp
        ${TemplateRootDir}/c++/view.cpp
        ${LibRootDir}/lib/core/core.cpp)
```

Shows as:
[image]